# how to subtract and add time difference

Tags: vb.net, datetime, ms-access, time, timespan

I'm doing this assignment that will get the total late of the day. There are 3 columns for late in database, it's the `lateAM`, `latePM` and `totallate`. In `lateAM` if the user attends at 7:31 am he is late for 1 min. In `latePM` if he attends at 1:05 pm he is late for 5 min. Then I need to add the `lateAM` and `latePM` to get the `totallate` which is 6 mins.

This is my code to get the `lateAM`

```
  Dim timelate As TimeSpan
    Dim time As Date = #7:30:00 AM#
    Dim zerotime As TimeSpan = TimeOfDay - TimeOfDay
    If TimeOfDay > #7:30:00 AM# Then
        timelate = TimeOfDay - time
    Else
        timelate = zerotime 'output 0:00:00
    End If

   Try
        Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(conString)
        query = "Insert into tbldtr(EmpID,empname,timeinAM,lateam) values ('" & txtInputID.Text & "', '" & txtEmpName.Text & "','" & TimeOfDay & "','" & timelate.ToString & "')"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully Time in AM")
        cnn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR: " & ErrorToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
```

This is my code to get the `latePM` and also to add `lateAM` and `latePM`

```
    Dim timelate As TimeSpan
    Dim time As Date = #1:00:00 PM#
    Dim zerotime As TimeSpan = TimeOfDay - TimeOfDay
    If TimeOfDay > #1:00:00 PM# Then
        timelate = TimeOfDay - time
    Else
        timelate = zerotime
    End If

          Try
        Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(conString)
        query = "update tbldtr set timeinPM = '" & TimeOfDay & "',latepm = '" & timelate.ToString & "', totallate = lateam + latepm"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully Time in PM")
        cnn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR: " & ErrorToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
```

My problem is I can't add the `lateAM` and `latePM`.
I'm using vb and msaccess as database. My `lateAM` and `latePM` columns have datatype `shorttext`.

Answer (score 1):

You should always store date/time as date so change your fields' data type.

Then:

```
query = "Insert into tbldtr(EmpID,empname,timeinAM,lateam) values ('" & txtInputID.Text & "', '" & txtEmpName.Text & "',#" & TimeOfDay.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#,#" & timelate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#)"
```

**Edit**

To store time only, use this format:

```
query = "Insert into tbldtr(EmpID,empname,timeinAM,lateam) values ('" & txtInputID.Text & "', '" & txtEmpName.Text & "',#" & TimeOfDay.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss") & "#,#" & timelate.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss") & "#)"
```

Comment: when im using date as data type instead of 0:01:00 is the output it always save 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: ( cc: @kenabaki ) - *"You should always store date/time as date"* - Yes, but `timelate` is not intended to be a date; it is intended to be a number of minutes, so its column type should be numeric. Also, an answer with dynamic SQL and raw user input is really setting a bad example.

Comment: @GordThompson: That depends. The questioneer operates with _TimeSpan_ which doesn't exist in Access but _Date_ can perfectly well hold the values (within it's boundaires, of course). Having _Date_, you can hold the resolution you wish down to milliseconds which leaves you free to calculate and display as needed later. Agree that _parameters_ are right to use, but you cannot educate in each an every question where this fact is not the cause of the issue raised. There are just so many examples around how to use parameters.